# how many colors do I have with <mat-toolbar>

Tags: angular-material

I want to change the color of my  but currently angular material only offers me 3 different colors 'primary', 'accent', or 'warn'.

Where do I find other colors that support  angular material?

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
```

Comment: You need to add the custom theme for all your required colors. Please review Angular Material Theme Guide - https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

The Color depends on the theme you choose.

In the link below, you have **primary** **accent** and **warn**

[Angular mat-toolbar Theming](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview#theming)

Answer (score 0):

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="primary">` for Indigo/Pink Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="accent">` for Indigo/Pink Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="warn">` for Indigo/Pink Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="primary">` for Deep Purple/Amber Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="accent">` for Deep Purple/Amber Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="warn">` for Deep Purple/Amber Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="primary">` for Pink/Blue Grey Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="accent">` for Pink/Blue Grey Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="warn">` for Pink/Blue Grey Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="primary">` for Purple/Green Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="accent">` for Purple/Green Theme:

[image]

Here is `<mat-toolbar color="warn">` for Purple/Green Theme:

[image]